# Why test for equality in sh scripts in an indirect way?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I often see this construct in sh scripts:

```
if [ "z$x" = z ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

Why don't they just write it like this?

```
if [ "$x" = "" ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

Comment: Because `[` is dumb and hateful.

Comment: It's actually not necessary. I think they somehow took the practice from `if` of batch files.

Comment: I believe there were some problems with empty string comparisons in some shells in some Unixes in use in the 80s or early 90s.  At least I remember seeing this way of comparing a lot in the early 1990s, and I've seen it less and less since, and my impression was that it was in scripts that were intended to be portable.

Comment: @EivindEklund Your comment seems to be the best possible answer. I must admit that I have seen no scripts in the early 90's ;)

Comment: @EivindEklund: That's what I assumed at first when I saw it, but then this page says a different reason: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestingAgainstTheNullString

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR short answer

In this construct:

```
if [ "z$x" = z ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

the `z` is a guard against funny content of `$x` and many other problems.

If you write it without the `z`:

```
if [ "$x" = "" ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

and `$x` contains the string `-x` you will get:

```
if [ "-x" = "" ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

and that confuses the hell out of some older implementations of `[`.

If you further omit the quotes around `$x` and `$x` contains the string `-f foo -o x` you will get:

```
if [ -f foo -o x = "" ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

and now it silently checks for something completely different.

the guard will prevent these maybe honest human errors maybe possibly malicious attacks to fall through silently. with the guard you either get the correct result or an error message. read on for an elaborate explanation.

---

Elaborate explanation

The `z` in

```
if [ "z$x" = z ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

is called a guard.

To explain why you want the guard I first want to explain the syntax of the bash conditional `if`. It is important to understand that `[` is not part of the syntax. It is a command. It is an alias to the `test` command. And in most current shells it is a builtin command.

The grammar rule for `if` is roughly as follows:

```
if command; then morecommands; else evenmorecommands; fi
```

(the `else` part is optional)

`command` can be any command. Really any command. What bash does when it encounters an `if` is roughly as follows:

1. Execute `command`.
2. Check the exit status of `command`.
3. If exit status is `0` then execute `morecommands`. If exit status is anything else, and the `else` part exists, then execute `evenmorecommands`.

Let's try that:

```
$ if true; then echo yay; else echo boo; fi
yay
$ if wat; then echo yay; else echo boo; fi
bash: wat: command not found
boo
$ if echo foo; then echo yay; else echo boo; fi
foo
yay
$ if cat foo; then echo yay; else echo boo; fi
cat: foo: No such file or directory
boo
```

Let's try the `test` command:

```
$ if test z = z; then echo yay; else echo boo; fi
yay
```

And the alias `[`:

```
$ if [ z = z ]; then echo yay; else echo boo; fi
yay
```

You see `[` is not part of the syntax. It is just a command.

Note that the `z` here has no special meaning. It is just a string.

Let's try the `[` command outside of an `if`:

```
$ [ z = z ]
```

Nothing happens? It returned an exit status. You can check the exit status with `echo $?`.

```
$ [ z = z ]
$ echo $?
0
```

Let's try unequal strings:

```
$ [ z = x ]
$ echo $?
1
```

Because `[` is a command it accepts parameters just like any other commands. In fact, the closing `]` is also a parameter, a mandatory parameter which must come last. If it is missing the command will complain:

```
$ [ z = z
bash: [: missing `]'
```

It is misleading that bash does the complaining. Actually the builtin command `[` does the complaining. We can see more clearly who does the complaining when we invoke the system `[`:

```
$ /usr/bin/[ z = z
/usr/bin/[: missing `]'
```

Interestingly the system `[` doesn't always insist on a closing `]`:

```
$ /usr/bin/[ --version
[ (GNU coreutils) 7.4
...
```

You need a space before the closing `]` otherwise it will not be recognized as a parameter:

```
$ [ z = z]
bash: [: missing `]'
```

You also need a space after the `[` otherwise bash will think you want to execute another command:

```
$ [z = z]
bash: [z: command not found
```

This is much more obvious when you use `test`:

```
$ testz = z
bash: testz: command not found
```

Remember `[` is just another name for `test`.

`[` can do more than just compare strings. It can compare numbers:

```
$ [ 1 -eq 1 ]
$ [ 42 -gt 0 ]
```

It can also check for the existence of files or directories:

```
$ [ -f filename ]
$ [ -d dirname ]
```

See `help [` or `man [` for more information about the capabilities of `[` (or `test`). `man` will show you the documentation for the system command. `help` will show you the documentation for the bash builtin command.

Now that I have covered the bases I can answer your question:

Why do people write this:

```
if [ "z$x" = z ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

and not this:

```
if [ "$x" = "" ]; then echo x is empty; fi
```

For brevity I will strip off the `if` because this is only about `[`.

The `z` in this construct:

```
[ "z$x" = z ]
```

is a guard against funny content of `$x` in combination with older implementations of `[`, and/or a guard against human error like forgetting to quote `$x`.

What happens when `$x` has funny content like `-f`?

This

```
[ "$x" = "" ]
```

will become

```
[ "-f" = "" ]
```

Some older implementations of `[` will get confused when the first parameter starts with a `-`. The `z` will make sure that the first parameter never starts with a `-` regardless of content of `$x`.

```
[ "z$x" = "z" ]
```

will become

```
[ "z-f" = "z" ]
```

What happens when you forgot to quote `$x`? Funny content like `-f foo -o x` can change the entire meaning of the test.

```
[ $x = "" ]
```

will become

```
[ -f foo -o x = "" ]
```

The test is now checking for the existence of the file foo and then logical or with whether `x` is the empty string. The worst part is that you won't even notice because there is no error message, only an exit status. If `$x` comes from user input this can even be used for malicious attacks.

With the guarding `z`

```
[ z$x = z ]
```

will become

```
[ z-f foo -o x = z ]
```

At least you will now get an error message:

```
$ [ z-f foo -o x = z ]; echo $?
bash: [: too many arguments
```

The guard also helps against the case of undefined variable instead of the empty string. Some older shells had different behaviour for undefined variable and empty string. This problem is basically solved because in modern shells undefined mostly behaves like an empty string.

Summary:

The quote around `$x` helps to make the undefined cases behave more like the empty string cases.

The guard before `$x` helps to further prevent all the other problems mentioned above.

The guard before `$x` will prevent all these possible errors:

- Funny content of `$x` (code injection by malicious user)
- old implementations of `[` (getting confused if string begins with `-`)
- forgetting to quote `$x` (will allow `-f foo -o x` to subvert the meaning of the test)
- undefined `$x`. (older implementations behave differently if undefined)

The guard will either do the right thing or raise an error message.

Modern implementations of `[` have fixed some of the problems and modern shells have some solutions for the other cases, but they have pitfalls of their own. The guarding `z` is not necessary if you are otherwise carefull, but it makes avoiding mistakes while writing simple tests so much more simpler.

See also:

- [bash pitfalls about quoting in tests](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D)
- [bash FAQ more details about test](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)
- [more about test](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)
- [more about quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)
- ["test" operator robustness in various shells](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/test/)

Comment: What about `[ "" = "$x" ]` instead of `[ "z$x" = "" ]`? Would it still get confused if `$x` is "-f"?

Comment: having the string literal in front is another relatively safe method to not get `[` confused from funny content in `$x`.

Answer (score 2):

For testing zero length, use `-z`:

```
if [ -z "$x" ] ; then
    echo x is empty
fi
```

With bash, you can use its `[[` that does not need quotes:

```
if [[ -z $x ]] ; then
    echo x is empty
fi
```

I just found the following in `man 1p sh`, the documentation of POSIX shell:

> Historical systems have also been unreliable given the common construct:
>
> ```
>     test "$response" = "expected string"
> ```
>
> One of the following is a more reliable form:
>
> ```
>     test "X$response" = "Xexpected string"
>     test "expected string" = "$response"
> ```
>
> Note  that the second form assumes that expected string could not be confused with any unary primary. If expected string starts with '-', '(', '!', or even '=', the first form should be used instead.

Comment: Ask who? I see this in all kinds of scripts, for example this question I just posted had it, and someone mentioned that it's for backwards compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18240617/2213023 I'd assume most people would just say they did it because someone else told them to. Thus I asked it here to get a general consensus.

Answer (score 1):

The short and simple answer: `[` is actually not a bash directive, while `[[` is.  It is instead a symlink to the command line utility `test`.

*Now for why:*

Like any other command line utility, `test` interprets anything starting with a `-` to be an option.  It also considers anything starting with `=` to be an operator.  If you don't prefix your arguments to `[` (or `test`) with an alpha character, there is no guarantee the test will work reliably.

Consider the values:

```
a=1
b=1
```

And the evaluation:

```
[ "$a" = "$b" ] && echo "Yes, they match"
```

Which is essentially running the following command (test ignores the closing `]` when its exec name is `[`):

```
test 1 = 1 ] && echo "Yes, they match"
```

Now consider the values:

```
a="-lt"
b="-lt"
```

The argument `-lt` is an option to test.  So when you perform the same test, it expands to:

```
test -lt = -lt ] && echo "Yes, they match"
```

Now, this is fine on Linux systems (or at least modern ones), since test has been rewritten to ignore options that precede or succeed the `=` or `!=` operators.  However, on some older UNIX systems, this will break with an error like:

```
test: -lt: unary operator expected
```

Comment: One minor correction: while `[` is indeed a symlink to `test`, it is usually also implemented as a shell built-in for efficiency.

Comment: Absolutely.  For '[' bash/dash maintains this syntactically the same as /usr/bin/[, but is actually implemented internally.  However, /bin/sh (not dash) does not and will actually execute the `test` variant.  It all depends on whether the OS has dash installed and whether the shell script implements an explicit `#!/bin/bash` shebang or just `#!/bin/sh`.  It may also depend on whether /bin/sh is a symlink to bash.  The `[` symlink is implemented for UNIX/POSIX compatibility (allowing Linux to run native UNIX shell scripts).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure x is defined :

```
 if [ ${x:-Z} = 'Z' ];then 
    echo x is empty
 fi
```

Comment: If you set `x=Z`, this code will report that `x is empty`, which is blatantly untrue.  There are ways to explicitly test for emptiness (`[ -z "$x" ]` amongst others) that are better.